# Securing End User-Defined Kubernetes Pods

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes, cloud, infrastructure

I am developing a game development platform that allows users to run their game servers within my Kubernetes cluster. What is everything that I need to restrict / configure to prevent malicious users from gaining access to resources they should not be allowed to access such as internal pods, Kubernetes access keys, image pull secrets, etc?

I'm currently looking at Network Policies to restrict access to internal IP addresses, but I'm not sure if they would still be able to enumerate DNS addresses to sensitive internal architecture. Would they still be able to somehow find out how my MongoDB, Redis, Kafka pods are configured?

Also, I'm aware Kubernetes puts an API token at the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` path. How do I disable this token from being created? Are there other sensitive files I need to remove / disable?

I've been researching everything I can think of, but I want to make sure that I'm not missing anything.

Pods are defined within a Deployment with a Service, and exposed via Nginx Ingress TCP / UDP ConfigMap. Example Configuration:

```
---
metadata:
  labels:
    app: game-server
  name: game-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: game-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: game-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: game-server
        name: game-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7777
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500M
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-registry-image-pull-secret
---
metadata:
  labels:
    app: game-server
    service: game-server
  name: game-server
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 7777
  selector:
    app: game-server
```

TL;DR: How do I run insecure, end user-defined Pods within my Kubernetes cluster safely?

Comment: Too broad of a question, you can't expect people to create your business logic for you. Just improve and if you fail on specific task, then you should ask it.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to define by business logic. I have plenty of business logic defined for my application. I need to secure pods created by external users. These pods need to run in isolation and not expose any sensitive information provided by Kubernetes while allowing external traffic. This would be standard to anyone who has created IaaS products within Kubernetes. None of this has anything to do with my business logic.

Comment: don't want to drag but if you are building a platform and asking how to secure entire platform that is also business logic.